# Field is referencing the wrong data

Tags: sugarcrm

Question: What is the best way to track a fields data source?

I have been going through numerous files and all the references that I can find are correct.

The issue is that the "Last Name" field is showing the contacts full name.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I am working with SugarCRM CE 6.5.13
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fields are defined in modules/SomeModules/vardefs.php or if it is a
   custom_field in the db table fields_meta_data
2. in the modules bean modules/SomeModules/SomeModule.php you can overwrite default behavior to generate for example a full_name like this:

For detail view:

```
    function fill_in_additional_detail_fields() {
        parent::fill_in_additional_detail_fields();
        $this->full_name = 'Something else';
    }
```

For list view:

```
    function fill_in_additional_list_fields() {
        parent::fill_in_additional_list_fields();
        $this->full_name = 'Something else';
    }
```

Or by overriding the standard function _create_proper_name_field:

```
 /**
 * This function helps generate the name and full_name member field
 * variables from the salutation, title, first_name and last_name fields.
 * It takes into account the locale format settings as well as ACL settings
 * if supported.
 */
public function _create_proper_name_field() {
    parent::_create_proper_name_field();

    $full_name = trim(trim($this->first_name) . ' ' . trim($this->last_name));

    if (!empty($full_name) && !empty($this->name)) {
        $full_name .= ' - ';
    }
    if (!empty($this->name)) {
        $full_name .= $this->name;
    }
    $this->full_name = $full_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your very insightful and complete answers.

Comment: With information you shared I was able to locate the error and although I was unable to fully use your code example to resolve the problem you did help me locate the problem with your clear explanation. In the end I just used substr() to read through the field value then removed the firstname and the trailing space then passed the remaining lastname to the field. Thank you again.